# Redux objects is being submited empty on submission

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am having an issue when I submit my form my object is being submitted empty when , and I confirmed this in the redux dev-tool as well. When I submit my form, a card is supposed to appear on the DOM with the info I entered into the form on it, or in react terms with the info passed down to the props of that component. Well when I submit the info is empty, and my redux dev tool is showing that object is empty on submission.

Here is my POST action

```
export const postRecipes = (recipe) => {
  
    const BASE_URL = `http://localhost:3001`
    const RECIPES_URL =`${BASE_URL}/recipes`
    const config = {
        method: "POST",
        body:JSON.stringify(recipe),
        headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Content-type": "application/json"
     }
    }

    return (dispatch) => {
      
      fetch(RECIPES_URL,config)
        .then(response =>{ response.json()})
        .then(recipe => { dispatch({ type: 'ADD_RECIPE', payload: recipe })
        
    })
    .catch((error) => console.log.error(error))
       
        
    };

    
    
  }
```

**Edit: added GET action for my retrieving my recipes saved to database**

```
export const getRecipes = () => {
  
    const BASE_URL = `http://localhost:3001`
    const RECIPES_URL =`${BASE_URL}/recipes`

    return (dispatch) => {
      dispatch({ type: 'START_FETCHING_RECIPES_REQUEST' });
      fetch(RECIPES_URL)
        .then(response =>{ return response.json()})
        .then(recipes => { dispatch({ type: 'GET_RECIPES', recipes })});
       
        
    };

    
    
  }
```

Here is my reducer action type for Adding the object(Hopefully I worded this correctly)

```
case 'START_ADDING_RECIPE':
            return{
                ...state,
                loading:true
            }

        case 'ADD_RECIPE':
            const recipe = {
                name: action.name,
                ingredients: action.ingredients,
                chef_name: action.chef_name,
                origin: action.origin,
                instructions: action.instructions,
                category_id: action.category_id
                
            }
```

**Edit: adding reducers for request see current state of my recipes**

```
case 'START_FETCHING_RECIPES_REQUEST':
            return {
                ...state,
            recipes: [...state.recipes],
            loading: true
        }
        case 'GET_RECIPES':
            return {
                ...state, recipes: action.recipes,
                loading: false
            }
```

**Edit: My mapDispatchToProps and mapDispatchToState functions**

```
const mapStateToProps = state =>{
    return{
        recipes: state.recipes,
        loading: state.loading

    }
}


const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch =>{
    return{
    postRecipes: recipe => dispatch(postRecipes(recipe)),
    getRecipes: () => dispatch(getRecipes()),
    deleteRecipe: recipeId => dispatch(deleteRecipe(recipeId))
    }
}
```

**Edit:Including my created store**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import manageRecipes from './reducers/manageRecipes';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension'

const composeEnhancer = composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(thunk))
const store = createStore(manageRecipes,composeEnhancer)

ReactDOM.render(
  
    <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
    </Provider>,
   
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

**Edit: I believe I added a few things in this code**
Here is the event handler that goes off when a user interacts with the submit button

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Select from 'react-select'
import axios from 'axios'
import '../index.css'



class RecipeInput extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            
            category_id: [],
            name:'',
            ingredients: '',
            chef_name: '',
            origin: '',
            instructions:''
            
        }
        

        
    }


      

    
    async getOptions(){
        const BASE_URL = `http://localhost:3001`
        const CATEGORIES_URL =`${BASE_URL}/categories`
        const res = await axios.get(CATEGORIES_URL)
        const data = res.data

        const options = data.map(d => ({
           
            
           
            'label' : d.category,
            'id' : d.id

            
        }))

        this.setState({category_id: options})
    }

    

    handleNameChange = (event) =>{
        this.setState({name:event.target.value})
    }

    handleInsChange = (event) =>{
        this.setState({instructions:event.target.value})
    }

    handleIngChange = (event) =>{
        this.setState({ingredients:event.target.value})
    }

    handleChefChange = (event) =>{
        this.setState({chef_name:event.target.value})
    }

    handleOriginChange = (event) =>{
        this.setState({origin:event.target.value})
    }

    handleChange = (event) =>{
        
        this.setState({category_id:event.id})
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.getOptions()
    }


    handleSubmit = (event) =>{
        alert(this.state.name + 'was set!')
        event.preventDefault();
        this.props.postRecipes(this.state)
        this.setState({
        name:'',
        ingredients: '',
        chef_name: '',
        origin: '',
        instructions: ''
       })
     
     
    }

    

    
    
        

    render(){
       let dropdown = 'form-select form-select-sm'
  
        return(
            <div>
                
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <Select options={this.state.category_id} onChange={this.handleChange} className={dropdown}/>
                    <div>
                    <label for='name'>Recipe Name:</label>
                    <input  className ="form-control" type='text' value={this.state.name} onChange={this.handleNameChange} />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                    <label for='name'>Country Origin:</label>
                    <input className ="form-control" type='text' value={this.state.origin} onChange={this.handleOriginChange} />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                    <label for='name'>Chef Name:</label>
                    
                    <input className ="form-control" type='text' value={this.state.chef_name} onChange={this.handleChefChange} />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                    <label for='name'>Ingredients:</label>
                    <textarea className ="form-control" cols="30" rows="5" type='text' value={this.state.ingredients} onChange={this.handleIngChange} />
                    
                    <label for='name'>Instructions:</label>
                    <textarea className ="form-control" cols="30" rows="5" type='text' value={this.state.instructions} onChange={this.handleInsChange} />
                    </div>
                    <input value='submit' type='submit'/>
                </form>
                
            </div>
        )
    }


 


}

export default RecipeInput
```

I feel like this is in my post action somewhere but not sure where, how can I correct this?

Answer (score 1):

The way I am understanding this, I could be wrong but here is my understanding,

In you RecipeInput class, you're calling handleSubmit(). In that function you're calling out to postRecipes() using this.state.

Where do you set the this.state variable after initializing it to the following?

```
this.state = {
            category_id: [],
            name:'',
            ingredients: '',
            chef_name: '',
            origin: '',
            instructions:''
            
        }
```

So the post request in fetch(RECIPES_URL,config), will send an empty object. So to change this, you will have to set this.states before calling the postRecipes() function.

Comment: I will update my code snippet, I reduced this for practical reasons. This is not the full input component.

Comment: I've updated the code there so you can see how the state is set.

Comment: `handleSubmit = (e) =>{
        e.preventDefault();
        this.setState({
        name:'',
        ingredients: '',
        chef_name: '',
        origin: '',
        instructions: ''
       })
     this.props.postRecipes(this.state)
     
    }`

By calling this.setState() aren't you clearing the data? and then sending the states to the function?

Comment: I thought I was resetting the form after submission.

Comment: Also, I put that line where I was invoking the postRecipe function back above the setSet part method, and the same issue occurs. That how I originally had it before this